# Extending MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I've run into problems extending the MySQLi class. It won't let me add any properties.

```
class MySQLii extends MySQLi {

 public $database;

 public function MySQLii($host, $username, $password, $database){

  // Initialize MySQLi
  parent::MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $database);

  // Save database name
  $this->database = $database;

 }

}

$mysqlii = new MySQLii('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');

var_dump($mysqlii);
```

> object(MySQLii)#1 (17) {
>   ["affected_rows"]=>   int(0)
>   ["client_info"]=>   string(48)
>   "mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 -
>   $Revision: 289630 $"
>   ["client_version"]=>   int(50005)
>   ["connect_errno"]=>   int(0)
>   ["connect_error"]=>   NULL
>   ["errno"]=>   int(0)   ["error"]=>
>   string(0) ""   ["field_count"]=>
>   int(0)   ["host_info"]=>   string(42)
>   "MySQL host info: Localhost via UNIX
>   socket"   ["info"]=>   NULL
>   ["insert_id"]=>   int(0)
>   ["server_info"]=>   string(6) "5.1.44"
>   ["server_version"]=>   int(50144)
>   ["sqlstate"]=>   string(5) "00000"
>   ["protocol_version"]=>   int(10)
>   ["thread_id"]=>   int(4019)
>   ["warning_count"]=>   int(0) }

Note the absence of the `database` property I added in the MySQLii constructor. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently extending the MySQLi class makes it impossible to add additional properties. Bad PHP. Bad.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, either I am missing something or you named your constructor `MySQLii` instead of [`__construct`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). (This is not Java ;))

Renaming it appropriately could solve the problem as it looks as if your constructor is not called.

Comment: You can substitute your constructor's function name for that of the class in PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a wrapper to `MySQLi` and `MySQLi_STMT` by extending both classes (as per PHP 5.3 and 5.2). I can confirm that while the variables don't appear when you dump it with `var_dump`, the class methods accesses the variables like any other normal object without problems.

```
class Foo extends MySQLi
{
    public $var = 'blah';

    public function blah()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->var;
$foo->blah();
```

Accessing the variable from outside of the class also works as expected. As long as you don't normally use `var_dump` to figure out which variable exists or other unorthodox functionality, just code as you normally do and you'll have no problems.