# Extending The MySQLi Class, Hidden Member Variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I've just started to extend the MySQLi class and found that member variables created in the child class don't display as part of the object when using `print_r` or `var_dump` etc.

Take for example this sample

```
class Database extends MySQLi {
    public function __construct( $h, $u, $p, $n ) {
        parent::__construct( $h, $u, $p, $n );

        $this->name = $n;
    }
}
```

When running the following, the member variables one would expect to see in an MySQLi object are present and output successfully. However, the member variables I create are not present.

```
$obj = new Database( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' )
print_r( $obj );
```

I found however that I can use calls to `echo $obj->name` successfully.

On further inspection I am able to successfully inspect the object using the following:

```
print_r( get_object_vars( $obj ) );

Array
(
    [name] => my_database
    [affected_rows] => 
    [client_info] => 
    [client_version] =>

[...]
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472622/extending-mysqli) but it doesn't really offer an answer- the accepted solution suggests that it's impossible, one answer comes to the same conclusion as me, and the other is irrelevant.

[The manual](http://uk.php.net/print_r) for `print_r()` suggests that in theory my member variables should be shown because they're not static.

> print_r(), var_dump() and var_export() will also show protected and
>   private properties of objects with PHP 5. Static class members will
>   not be shown.

Is there a way in which I can extend the MySQLi class and be able to quickly debug my database objects using `print_r` without the requirement for `get_object_vars()`. Is this intended behavior or a bug which should be reported to the developers of PHP?

I am using PHP Version 5.3.5 on Windows 7. I've yet to test this on my Linux development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - by overwriting the [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)-Magic Method, you can dump it however you want by writing your own dumping function. As you have your own environment, you might also check out debugging php with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and get a lot more power.

Comment: I've finally had a chance to have a play around with this. Whilst `function __toString() { return print_r( get_object_vars( $this ), true ); }` allows me to `echo $extended_object` it doesn't allow me to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` still. Am I on the right track or is this another limitation?

Comment: That's correct. `print_r()` and `var_dump()` are internal functions, which perform their own logic - `__toString()` is called when you try to `printf()` or `echo()` a variable and may contain your logic instead. So you can perfectly use the `__toString()`-method to dump all variables you want. In your specific case, you could parse the inheritance class backwards with `get_parent_class()` and dump this one as well.